# How to decode log data from bscscan API using PHP?

Tags: logs, php

I'm pulling fight logs from a BSC contract via bscscan API. The `data` record, which should be a set 6 different values, looks like this: `0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b501600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030004750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000522000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000046300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000066e52ba3af511`

Here is the entire entry record:

```
 {
                "address": "0x39bea96e13453ed52a734b6aceed4c41f57b2271",
                "topics": [
                    "0x7a58aac6530017822bf3210fccef7efa31f56277f19966bc887bfb11f40ca96d",
                    "0x0000000000000000000000002c238ad3411bdcdc0e4175f9320924ebc335e9e0",
                    "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004ce14"
                ],
                "data": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b501600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030004750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000522000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000046300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000066e52ba3af511e",
                "blockNumber": "0x8fb8df",
                "timeStamp": "0x60fb3442",
                "gasPrice": "0x12a05f200",
                "gasUsed": "0x265a1",
                "logIndex": "0x1b8",
                "transactionHash": "0xf6b8279edcf9f5c76d067fc1ca529f7e8fd4f0be4b7e277ba28556e19ed3ced0",
                "transactionIndex": "0x72"
            },
```

How can I use vanilla PHP to decode this string into the 6 data values as they can be seen here:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xf6b8279edcf9f5c76d067fc1ca529f7e8fd4f0be4b7e277ba28556e19ed3ced0#eventlog

I'd rather not use a W3 or other library.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62018942/how-to-decode-response-of-eth-getlogs-with-php

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this PHP works for the above:

```
$data = $tx['data'];
$data_cleaned = str_replace("0x" , "" , $data);
$data_split =  str_split($data_cleaned, 64);
```